# How to set .gdb as Python script tool parameter?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, python-script-tool, parameters

I was thinking the Geodataset (as shown in figure 1) would be the right choice if I want to use .gdb as a parameter when using script tool, but it didn't work since I couldn't add my gdb to the box, shown in figure 2. What is the right parameter type I should use here?
[image]

[image]

Using 10.3.1 ArcGIS Advance License.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter you need is:
workspace

Comment: It would be good to add a source too: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/002t/pdf/Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf